# How to minimise bind9 memory footprint?

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, memory, bind

I'm running bind 9.5.1 on debian lenny. Unfortunately the machine does not have a lot of memory (only 500MB) and with apache, db and mailserver this is getting tight. Currently bind takes about 10% and is the top consumer of memory - any clues to diminish this? Already cut down on cache, can't really find more options. Perhaps alternative dns server? It only serves a couple domains.

Comment: Is it for authoritative service or for recursive one?

Comment: This is for an authoritative service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, BIND is a memory hog.  Personally, I'm a fan of tinydns part of [djbdns](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns.html) for low-memory footprint DNS service.  It's not like BIND at all in terms of config and management, but it's damn small, quite fast, and once you get used to it, I think it's better than BIND in many ways.

Comment: I completely agree with this -- ditch bind and use tinydns + dnscache.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bind for authoritative hosting of domains, or for a caching resolver?

If for authoritative hosting, turn off recursion (there's no need for a cache if you're not doing recursion); or try tinydns.

If for caching/recursive lookups, then give a lighter caching resolver a shot (like dnscachex).

Failing that, third-party DNS hosting is readily available.

Comment: The former - authoritative hosting of two domains. Will give a go at tiny dns. Otherwise I would have used nscd.